# SQL Email query does not stop sending email

Tags: mysql, email

I have recently encountered a problem.

I ran an SQL Query that checks against a database table for the date and matches it against today's date.

If they matches, The query will retrieve the email of all who has not done the survey and email them an notification email.

As I am using fake data to test out the script, so the emails are all not valid.
I set a job scheduler that runs the script daily. 
So i tested it out and my result was pleasant at first.

The emails that are not valid was returned back to me with an error message "Delivery has failed to these recipents or groups: blahblah@blahblah.com.sg"

*Which was fine with me. There are various fake email data*

**But suddenly, i received an infinite email error message loop about one fake email.**

It is just this email "126@student.tp.edu.sg" that keeps looping again and again. Other fake emails did not loop...

I removed the job scheduler, disconnected from my sql server and even shut down my computer. Yet when my computer was shut down, The mail is still being sent!

So I do not think it was an error with the query.

Comment: Is there no out of office, automated responses etc set up on the mail account that you use to send e-mails? Or is it full? If anyone of these sends a message to it, it can be an infinite loop, until you get rid of the outgoing message on your account. This is just a wild guess though.

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: @Tanner It is mySQL~

Comment: I did not set any rule in my office to auto-reply to the emails. Even if so, it is weird that all fake emails didnt get an infinite loop and only "126@student.tp.edu.sg" gets the infinite looping....